# YouTube Post Comment button missing most of the time

Tags: youtube

For some odd reason the "Post Comment" button seems to be missing from YouTube:

[image]

I'm using the current version of Chrome and it's frustrating because I comment frequently.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot shows the dark theme, so you are using [Youtube New](http://youtube.com/new). This issue could be related to it. Try to go back to "Youtube Old". To do so,

1. Click on the account icon
2. Click on "Restore Old Youtube"

Comment: Thank you, that is upsetting I really liked the dark theme its much easier then the endless white space. :(  -Thanks Obama

Comment: @KellyBean : Don't forget to send your comments to Google.

Comment: Yes, when I switched back it asked for feedback and I made sure to mention it.